# Get an "EXC_BAD_ACCESS" error, and I have no clue why

Tags: c, runtime-error

Here's the code I've got. It compiles fine, and I simply can't see what might be going wrong:

```
    // This program takes a quadratic from the user, and prints the solution(s) if they exist. 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <complex.h>


//Make sign function for switch test - because in the switch expression itself, C refused to believe x/|x| is an integer...
int sign(float f){
    printf("\n\nSIGN CALL OK\n\n");
    int sign=f/cabs(f);
    return sign;
}

// Define quadratic structure 
typedef struct quadratic{
    float a, b, c;
    float discriminant;
    float real_root_1;
    float real_root_2;
    float complex_root;
} Quadratic;

// 'Redefine' malloc to also check allocation of memory when called.

Quadratic* xmalloc(size_t n){
    printf("\n\nXMALLOC CALL OK\n\n");
    Quadratic* p = malloc(n);
    if (p == NULL) {
        printf("\n ERROR: Unable to allocate memory! \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    return p;
}

// newquadratic lets the user define the quadratic to be solved, and returns the pointer to its structure. 

Quadratic* newquadratic() {
    Quadratic* q = xmalloc(sizeof *q);
    printf("\n Please enter the coefficients of the quadratic separated by spaces: ");
    scanf("%g, %g, %g", q->a, q->b, q->c);
    printf("\n\nDATA ACCEPTED\n\n");
    return q;
}

// solve takes the existing data from the quadratics structure and defines the remaining quantities, depending on which
// case we get for the 'sign of the discriminant'.

int solve(Quadratic eqn){
    printf("\n\nSOLVE CALL OK\n\n");
    eqn.discriminant = (eqn.b*eqn.b - 4*eqn.a*eqn.c);

    switch (sign(eqn.discriminant)) {
        case -1:
            eqn.real_root_1 = (-eqn.b+sqrt(eqn.discriminant))/(2*eqn.a);
            eqn.real_root_2 = (-eqn.b-sqrt(eqn.discriminant))/(2*eqn.a);
            break;
        case 0:
            eqn.real_root_1 = (-eqn.b+sqrt(eqn.discriminant))/(2*eqn.a);
            break;
        case 1:
            eqn.complex_root = (-eqn.b+sqrt(eqn.discriminant))/(2*eqn.a);
            break;
    }
    return sign(eqn.discriminant);
}

//main also uses sign of the discriminant (as returned by solve) to decide how to behave appropriately for the case it receives.

int main () {

    Quadratic* eqn=newquadratic();

    printf("\n\n GET QUADRATIC OK\n\n");

    switch (solve(*eqn)) {
        case -1:
            printf("\n\n We have two real solutions, %g and %g", eqn->real_root_1, eqn->real_root_2);
            break;
        case 0:
            printf("\n\n We have one repeated real solution, %g", eqn->real_root_1);
            break;
        case 1:
            printf("\n\n We have two complex solutions, %g%+gi and %g%-gi", creal(eqn->complex_root),cimag(eqn->complex_root),creal(eqn->complex_root),(-1)*cimag(eqn->complex_root));
            break;
    }

        return 0;
}
```

xmalloc calls correctly, and we get to the stage where the user is to input the 3 coefficients. As soon as return is pushed we get the error.

Comment: Did you verify the size of the chunk of memory that xmalloc is allocating?

Comment: No.. I'm not even sure how I would do that, or what I would need to do if this was the problem! I'm only 8 weeks into a first course.

Comment: You could start by printing the value of n being passed to malloc; that would at least tell you the size you're asking for.

Comment: Well that's one issue I've always had with malloc which I didn't think was too bad.. but the line reads Quadratic *q = malloc(sizeof *q); so I feed malloc with the size of a quadratic structure, which I'm also declaring at the time.. I don't know how on earth sizeof makes sense of *q before it's been declared independently. I'll have a go at trying to see if I can get any useful info out of it..

Comment: the code Quadratic* p;
 printf("\n Size of quadratic structure %lu", sizeof *p);
 Quadratic* q = xmalloc(sizeof *q);
 printf("\nMem allocated by malloc %lu", sizeof *q);

Said my structure has size 28, and that malloc was assigning *q 28 also..

Comment: Sorry that code didn't turn out well in that comment..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in your function newquadratic.

The scanf function expects to be given the address of the variables into which it should put the results, while you've actually passed it the values that the variables hold.

To fix, pass the address of a, b and c like so: (add the `&` characters)

```
Quadratic* newquadratic() 
{
    Quadratic* q = xmalloc(sizeof *q);
    printf("\n Please enter the coefficients of the quadratic separated by spaces: ");
    scanf("%g, %g, %g", &q->a, &q->b, &q->c);
    printf("\n\nDATA ACCEPTED\n\n");
    return q;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this sorted it. For some reason I though q->a was the pointer to a in q..!

Comment: :grin: You're welcome. Its easily done. Especially when so new to the course. Syntax may bust your head over and over again, until one day, it just clicks.